# Binding Sharepoint list data to kendo grid

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have a search page, where user enter fields and click on search button. Then I am making ajax call to Sharepoint 2013 list with search query and fetching data. After fetching data I am binding data to Kendo grid.

This SharePoint list contains different type of fields like: look up, choice, text field. Data from choice column, text field types are getting bind to grid easily, I am able to see the data too. But data from look up columns is not being seen in Kendo Grid.

Instead of data, its showing

> [object Object]

Below is the code of ajax call I am making and in success I am binding data to Kendo Grid.

```
function fetchData(webUrl, filterString){
    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Inventory')/Items?$filter="+filterString,
        method: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        headers:{
            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function(data){
            var grid = $('#grdInventory').getKendoGrid();
            grid.dataSource.data(data.d.results);
            grid.refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

- Below is the screenshot of the Grid: In Grid=

ID, short description, Analytic ID, Analytic Name are text type column

Production status is choice column,

State, Platform are look up column in SharePoint

[image: I circled the errors which is being seen]

- Below is the screenshot of data being seen in Browser Console:

[image: Circled lookup Columns]

Can anyone please help me or give me hint of how to display look up column data in Kendo Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Before passing data.d.results to the grid you will probably want to modify it or create a new array of key/value pairs. Some field types that will probably need some modifications:

- Multichoice
- Taxonomy
- DateTime
- Lookup
- Possibly, multiline fields with rich text enabled

for example, you want something like this (I didn't run or tested this code):

```
for(var i; i < data.d.results.length; i++){   
   for(var field in data.d.results[i] ){
      if(data.d.results[i][field] && data.d.results[i][field].Value){
           data.d.results[i][field] = data.d.results[i][field].Value;
      } 
      // if(field == 'State') {// do something with data.d.results[i][field]}
   }
}
```

It's a very simplistic example. If we want to properly convert the data, we need a separate REST call to get the list fields so that we can get field types as well. Right now, we can only guess what type is inside the field value.

#### JavaScript enhancement: Array `forEach` *method* instead of a `for` *loop*

(source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

The above for loop can be rewritten to use the JavaScript forEach method on an Array.
Shorter, easier to read and use:

```
data.d.results.forEach(function(result){
    for(var field in result ){
        if(result[field] && result[field].Value){
            result[field] = result[field].Value;
        }
        // if(field == 'State') {// do something with data.d.results[i][field]}
     }
});
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it is an Object with key/value pairs, not an Array. Quick and dirty examination can be done with the toString method of an Object: ``data.d.results[i][field].toString()``